# After installing MongoDB with Homebrew on MacOS (Intel Processor), Mongo throws the Error

Tags: mongodb, macos, homebrew

Check xcode is installed

```
~ % xcode-select --install
xcode-select: error: command line tools are already installed, use "Software Update" to install updates
```

Update tap

```
~ % brew tap mongodb/brew
Running `brew update --preinstall`...
==> Auto-updated Homebrew!
Updated 2 taps (homebrew/core and homebrew/cask).
==> New Formulae
opendht
==> Updated Formulae
Updated 20 formulae.
==> Updated Casks
Updated 18 casks.
```

Install mongodb-community 5.0

```
~ % brew install mongodb-community@5.0
...
```

Check localisation

```
~ % brew --prefix
/usr/local
```

Start Mongodb

```
~ % brew services restart mongodb-community@5.0
Stopping `mongodb-community`... (might take a while)
==> Successfully stopped `mongodb-community` (label: homebrew.mxcl.mongodb-community)
==> Successfully started `mongodb-community` (label: homebrew.mxcl.mongodb-community)
```

Go to Mongo and THERE IS THE ERROR

```
~ % mongo
MongoDB shell version v5.0.6
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/?compressors=disabled&gssapiServiceName=mongodb
Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017, connection attempt failed: SocketException: Error connecting to 127.0.0.1:27017 :: caused by :: Connection refused :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:372:17
@(connect):2:6
exception: connect failed
exiting with code 1
```

Here also

```
~ % mongosh
Current Mongosh Log ID: 62270cdee016a9d630e71ef8
Connecting to:      mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/?directConnection=true&serverSelectionTimeoutMS=2000&appName=mongosh+1.2.2
MongoNetworkError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017
```

Who can help?

Comment: Getting same issues